# Oracle Sql Sum/Subtraction Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to report on two separate things in Oracle. `Priority` and `Non-Priority`. However, the `Non-Priority` statement also includes the count from the `Priority` statement. How can I subtract the `Priority` count from the `Non-Priority` count? Currently, the results are:

**Priority:** 3
**Non-Priority:** 84

But it should be:

**Priority:** 3
**Non-Priority:** 81

```
Select x.*, y.*
from
(Select count(distinct archivedqueue.batchnum) "Priority"
from archivedqueue
inner join scanninglog
on scanninglog.batchnum = archivedqueue.batchnum
inner join itemdata
on itemdata.batchnum = archivedqueue.batchnum
inner join itemdata
on itemdata.batchnum = scanninglog.batchnum
where (ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATESTARTED>=TO_DATE ('05-MAY-14')) -- Begin Date Range
and ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATESTARTED<TO_DATE ('09-MAY-14')      -- End Date Range
and (ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATEENDED>=TO_DATE ('05-MAY-14'))     -- Begin Date Range
and ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATEENDED<TO_DATE ('09-MAY-14')        -- End Date Range
and archivedqueue.usernum = '190'
and (archivedqueue.status = '8'
or scanninglog.actionnum = '8')
and (instr(itemdata.itemname, 'ANES OP') > 0
or instr(itemdata.itemname, 'TPN') > 0
or instr(itemdata.itemname, 'CODE BLUE') > 0))x ,
(Select count(distinct archivedqueue.batchnum) "Non-Priority"
from archivedqueue
inner join scanninglog
on scanninglog.batchnum = archivedqueue.batchnum
where (ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATESTARTED>=TO_DATE ('05-MAY-14')) -- Begin Date Range
and ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATESTARTED<TO_DATE ('09-MAY-14')      -- End Date Range
and (ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATEENDED>=TO_DATE ('05-MAY-14'))     -- Begin Date Range
and ARCHIVEDQUEUE.DATEENDED<TO_DATE ('09-MAY-14')        -- End Date Range
and archivedqueue.usernum = '190'
and (archivedqueue.status = '8'
or scanninglog.actionnum = '8')) Y ;
```

Comment: How about adding `and (instr(itemdata.itemname, 'ANES OP') <= 0
or instr(itemdata.itemname, 'TPN') <= 0
or instr(itemdata.itemname, 'CODE BLUE') <= 0)` to the second `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you notice you have 2 similar queries in 1 query? There is always a better way, usually by using a CASE statement. :)

Also, you use the table ITEMDATA twice. But you join on the same value, so once is enough. Please always use table aliases to make your life easier. You might have spotted this.

**edit**: replaced instr() with like '%xx%'.

```
Select count(distinct aq.batchnum) amount
,      case when it.itemname like '%ANES OP%' then 'prio'
            when it.itemname like '%TPN%' then 'prio'
            when it.itemname like '%CODE BLUE%' then 'prio'
            else 'non-prio'
   end prio_type
from   archivedqueue aq
join   scanninglog   sl on sl.batchnum = aq.batchnum
join   itemdata      it on it.batchnum = aq.batchnum
where  aq.DATESTARTED >= TO_DATE('05-MAY-14') -- Begin Date Range
and    aq.DATESTARTED < TO_DATE('09-MAY-14')  -- End Date Range
and    aq.DATEENDED >= TO_DATE('05-MAY-14')   -- Begin Date Range
and    aq.DATEENDED < TO_DATE('09-MAY-14')    -- End Date Range
and    aq.usernum = '190'
and    (aq.status = '8' or sl.actionnum = '8')
group by case when it.itemname like '%ANES OP%' then 'prio'
              when it.itemname like '%TPN%' then 'prio'
              when it.itemname like '%CODE BLUE%' then 'prio'
              else 'non-prio'
   end
```